# $.browser.msie no longer works in jQuery 1.9. Where's the replacement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the replacement for $.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645803/whats-the-replacement-for-browser)

I rely on jQuery's deprecated `$.browser` functionality to apply quirk fixes for certain browsers. Example:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) {
```

This functionality was [removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) in jQuery 1.9 so I'm looking for an alternative. jQuery suggests using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for feature detection, but that plugin doesn't appear to cover the functionality I need. What's the (un)official replacement for this functionality?

Comment: Modernizr does provide that functionality.

Comment: What feature are you testing support for?

Comment: "that plugin doesn't appear to cover the **unspecified** functionality I need" — this doesn't make it easy to help!

Comment: Get the migration plugin - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: @DominicBarnes: I'm making a quick fix to code I wrote a while ago, but it appears that `$().removeClass` didn't work properly in IE so I added a browser check. I'll reinvestigate that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9

From jQuery API documentation:

> Rather than using `$.browser` to detect the current user agent and alter
>   the page presentation based on which browser is running, it is a good
>   practice to **use feature detection**. To make this process simpler,
>   jQuery performs many such tests and sets properties of the
>   `jQuery.support` object.

For a more advanced feature detection you shoul yse [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as @Pointy suggested.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll remember that from now on. But I'm updating old code right now and rewriting that for feature detection would take more time.

Answer (score 2):

If you import Modernizr, you can test for an IE version with something like this:

```
if ($('body').is('.lt-ie9 *')) {
  // IE8, 7, 6 ...
}
```

*edit* — oops I fixed it; `$(document)` doesn't work and I can't remember why at the moment.

Modernizr also has lots of more specific feature detection abilities, and it's configurable so you can get only the detection you need. It can't detect everything; things like layout bugs are hard to detect automatically.