# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined

Tags: jquery, railstutorial.org

I am working through the examples in chapter 8 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I am getting the above error on my pages, and my dropdown menu isn't working.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
/* ===================================================
 * bootstrap-transition.js v2.0.0
 * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#transitions
 * ===================================================
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ========================================================== */


!function( $ ) {

  $(function () {

    "use strict"

    /* CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (https://gist.github.com/373874)
     * ======================================================= */

    $.support.transition = (function () {
      var thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement
        , thisStyle = thisBody.style
        , support = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined

      return support && {
        end: (function () {
          var transitionEnd = "TransitionEnd"
          if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined
            transitionEnd = "webkitTransitionEnd"
          } else if ( $.browser.mozilla ) {
            transitionEnd = "transitionend"
          } else if ( $.browser.opera ) {
            transitionEnd = "oTransitionEnd"
          }
          return transitionEnd
        }())
      }
    })()

  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgrade your bootstrap-sass gem to the most recent version by updating your Gemfile with the line:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.0.1'
```

I was having issues and it was because I was running version 2.0.0 of that gem. Not sure what version they recommend running in the tutorial, but upgrading to the most recent version shouldn't hurt you.

Comment: Worked for me too (After restarting the server)

Answer (score 16):

The problem I think is this bit here: `$.browser.webkit` - apparently $.browser has been removed in jQuery 1.9+.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645803/whats-the-replacement-for-browser) there is no direct replacement, however by using [this plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) you should be able to restore the functionality of that tag.