# How to determine what browser is used by the client using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client, detection

How do i detect what browser does the client using?

i saw there is a $.browser in Jquery API Documention but its not longer works in jQuery 1.9.1.

any suggestions?

Comment: *Why* do you want to know the browser ? Did you look at why they removed it ? What do you want more than `navigator.userAgent` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the replacement for $.browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645803/whats-the-replacement-for-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/) and call the `$.browser`. It will work!

Using the plugin is easy; just include it immediately after the script tag for jQuery, for example.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$.each($.browser, function(i, val) {
  $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
  .appendTo( document.body );
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hcgtr/) (See Migrate 1.1.0 check box is checked on left side)

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to use feature detection instead of browser detection.
Here is some detail about feature detection:

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/
```

But for answer to your question, you can use this code to detect browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/mozilla/i) && 
        ! navigator.userAgent.match(/webkit/i) ){
        alert('Mozilla');
    }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

$.browser has been removed in 1.9 as it's was suggested feature detection was preferred via $.support

Check 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Answer (score 1):

See this
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

Use  **[jQuery Migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/)**  as William suggested